# Rich text editing on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs, contenteditable, createjs

Are there any rich text editing libraries which can be used with HTML5 canvas? I have tried looking into:

1. Hallo Editor
   It points to createjs.org which is not a canvas library. 
   http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/hallo-editor/
2. Froala (Awesome library with lots of features)
   https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/inline

I am looking something similar which works with HTML5 Canvas element.

Answer (score 8):

Well,there is Carota at http://earwicker.com/carota. And a new one is currently under development at http://richtextjs.com (DISCLAIMER, I am the author).

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 Canvas is not a good target for rich text, since its capabilities are super limited. There are tons of great HTML DOM solutions, so the best option if you have a canvas app is to use something like the EaselJS DOMElement to wrap DOM-based elements, and control them like a child of the EaselJS display list.

- http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/DOMElement.html
- http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DOMElement.html

Comment: Google Docs targets HTML5 Canvas in their editor